# static variable inside static method in java

Tags: java, static, static-methods

While declaring a variable as static inside static method is giving error(compile time error).
My code is here:-

```
public class MainStatic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Value of static variable is"+print(10));    
    }
    public static void print(int number ) {
        static int x = number;
        ++x;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

I am getting compile time error as :-
"Illegal modifier for parameter x; only final is permitted".
As a static method doesn't depend on instance of class then why i am not able to declare a static variable inside static method ?
But it is accessible if i declare the variable inside class out of the method ?

Comment: You do not need static there. Do you ?

Comment: Inside methods the scope modifiers (`static`, `public`, etc) are not available. The scope is always the method.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to know that why static variable declaration is not allowed inside static method ?

Comment: @shankarDayalupadhyay Static in Java basically means "belongs to a class (not an instance)". As such, a variable belonging to the class should be declared directly inside the class body, not inside a method. Java *does not support* static local variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static variable belongs to the class and can be modified by anyone allowed according to the variable's access modifier. A local method variable only exists within the method (and during the execution of it) and can't be accessed by anyone outside of this method. It simply doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

Local variables exist only at the time of invocation. Static doesn't (and can't) affect them.

Comment: If i understand it properly then it means:- static variable doesn't play any role at the time of invocation of method, it only gets affected as global variable.

Comment: A local variable has no relationship to the *class* or whether instances of it exist. It's life is entirely contained when the method is being run. Not having to worry about classes. That lucky instance variable.